# How to use VBA to insert Excel data into Word, and export it as PDF?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, export-to-pdf

I have an excel sheet that has information in its rows for faxing. I need to loop through the populated rows of that sheet, and open the Word template on each row. Once template is open, I need to swap placeholders in the Word doc with the information in the actual row of the worksheet, then export is as PDF.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Dim wsMailing As Worksheet
Set wsMailing = wb.Sheets("Mailing List")


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' SECTION  1: DOC  CREATION
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

'sets up the framework for using Word 
Dim wordApp As Object
Dim wordDoc As Object
Dim owner, address1, address2, city, state, zipcode, insCo, fax1,  name, polnum As String


Dim n, j As Integer

Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")


'now we begin the loop for the mailing sheet that is being used

n = wsMailing.Range("A:A").Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For j = 2 To n


    'first we choose which word doc gets used

        'opens the word doc that has the template  for sending out 

        Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\cd\LEQ_VOC & Illustration Request.docx")

        'collects the  strings needed for the document
        owner = wsMailing.Range("E" & j).Value
        address1 = wsMailing.Range("F" & j).Value
        address2 = wsMailing.Range("G" & j).Value
        city = wsMailing.Range("H" & j).Value
        state = wsMailing.Range("I" & j).Value
        zipcode = wsMailing.Range("J" & j).Value
        insCo = wsMailing.Range("K" & j).Value
        fax1 = wsMailing.Range("L" & j).Value
        name = wsMailing.Range("M" & j).Value
        polnum = wsMailing.Range("N" & j).Value


        'fills in the word doc with the missing fields
        wordDoc.Find.Execute FindText:="<<InsuranceCompanyName>>", ReplaceWith:=insCo, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        wordDoc.Find.Execute FindText:="<<Fax1>>", ReplaceWith:=fax1, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        wordDoc.Find.Execute FindText:="<<OwnerName>>", ReplaceWith:=owner, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        wordDoc.Find.Execute FindText:="<<Address1>>", ReplaceWith:=address1, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        wordDoc.Find.Execute FindText:="<<Address2>>", ReplaceWith:=address2, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        wordDoc.Find.Execute FindText:="<<City>>", ReplaceWith:=city, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        wordDoc.Find.Execute FindText:="<<State>>", ReplaceWith:=state, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        wordDoc.Find.Execute FindText:="<<ZipCode>>", ReplaceWith:=zipcode, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        wordDoc.Find.Execute FindText:="<<Name>>", ReplaceWith:=name, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        wordDoc.Find.Execute FindText:="<<PolicyNumber>>", ReplaceWith:=polnum, Replace:=wdReplaceAll



        'this section saves the word doc in the folder as a pdf
        wordDoc.SaveAs ("C:\Users\cd\" & wsMailing.Range("N" & j).Value & "_" & wsMailing.Range("C" & j).Value & ".pdf")



    'need to close word now that it has been opened before the next loop

    wordDoc.Documents(1).Close

Next
```

When I run this, it gets hung up and Excel freezes. I get the error message "Microsoft Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action" and then I have to restart the computer to get it to respond again.

And the line that causes the program to freeze is

```
Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\cd\LEQ_VOC & Illustration Request.docx")
```

(Microsoft Word is not already up and running when I run this. It is completely closed.)

Comment: What line exactly does it get hung up on? Does it fill the word document(s) correctly first?

Comment: It gets stuck on the line that tries to open the document. wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open.......

Comment: It also doesn't actually open the word app when it hits the line to create object in the beginning

Comment: Take note that `Dim owner, address1, address2, city, state, zipcode, insCo, fax1,  name, polnum As String` is only declaring `polnum` as a `String` - the rest are being declared as `Variant`. You should write that as `Dim owner as String, address1 as String`, etc.

Comment: This shouldn't even compile, as you have an `End If` without an `If` right  before your `wordDoc.Documents(1).Close` line. You need to include your full code snippet, from `Sub` to `End Sub`.

Comment: If you wish to make Word visible straight away, then underneath your line `Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")`, just add `wordApp.Visible = True`

Comment: I am included the minimum amount of code to show the issue like instructed, not the full Sub to End Sub and the End If was left over from copying over just a section. The actual bit of coding has a corresponding If statement that goes along with it. That isn't the issue with it not opening the document properly.

Comment: I don't really mind that word isn't visible, just that it isn't opening and that trying to open the document freezes everything

Comment: @CassandraDurell What is the value of `n` when you start your loop?

Comment: It's the number that is the last row in the sheet.

Comment: Mail merge could do what you're suggesting. Why vba?

Comment: @CassandraDurell So it's 1048576? Or another number? My point is that if you're trying to do this for, say, 10,000 rows, then Excel is bound to trip up.

Comment: Did you get your code working?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, in my case in the VBA editor I had to go to Tools -> References,

[image]

...and enable Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library to be able to properly access Excel 2016 Object Model. With different version of Office, the module to be enabled might have a different version number.

[image]

---

Here I have changed the structure slightly, to simplify things, but essentially `.Content` was missing.

So instead of:
    `wordDoc.Find.Execute`
, it would be:
    `wordDoc.Content.Find.Execute`

So it looks like this:

```
        With wordDoc.Content.Find
            .Execute FindText:="<<InsuranceCompanyName>>", ReplaceWith:=insCo, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            .Execute FindText:="<<Fax1>>", ReplaceWith:=fax1, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            .Execute FindText:="<<OwnerName>>", ReplaceWith:=owner, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            .Execute FindText:="<<Address1>>", ReplaceWith:=address1, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            .Execute FindText:="<<Address2>>", ReplaceWith:=address2, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            .Execute FindText:="<<City>>", ReplaceWith:=city, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            .Execute FindText:="<<State>>", ReplaceWith:=state, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            .Execute FindText:="<<ZipCode>>", ReplaceWith:=zipcode, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            .Execute FindText:="<<Name>>", ReplaceWith:=name, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            .Execute FindText:="<<PolicyNumber>>", ReplaceWith:=polnum, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
```

---

Next thing I had to change was the SaveAs PDF thing.

This saves a file with .pdf extension, but when you actually try to open it, it doesn't open. A PDF file saved this way, inside is still a Word Document (.docx). Same as if you rename a Word Document to PDF. It is still a Word Document.

This is replaced:

```
wordDoc.SaveAs ("C:\Users\cd\" & wsMailing.Range("N" & j).Value & "_" & wsMailing.Range("C" & j).Value & ".pdf")
```

with this:

```
wordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat "C:\Users\cd\" & wsMailing.Range("N" & j).Value & "_" & wsMailing.Range("C" & j).Value & ".pdf", wdExportFormatPDF
```

---

Last thing to change was how the Word Document is closed. 
This doesn't close the document, because `wordDoc` is the one and only document, so it is not a collection of documents, therefore you cannot refer to the first document contained by `wordDoc`:

```
wordDoc.Documents(1).Close
```

Instead it is simply:

```
wordDoc.Close (wdDoNotSaveChanges)
```

`wdDoNotSaveChanges` had to be added to make sure that your Word document template doesn't get saved with the content of the first PDF file.

Without this your first PDF would get created and saved, together with the Word document saved containing the same as the PDF file.

In the second iteration of the For Loop there would be nothing to replace because all the placeholders `<<...>>` would be gone.

From then on all PDF files would have exactly the same content.

I hope this helps.

---

The whole code block again to help copy and paste as one unit:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Dim wsMailing As Worksheet
Set wsMailing = wb.Sheets("Mailing List")


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' SECTION  1: DOC  CREATION
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

'sets up the framework for using Word
Dim wordApp As Object
Dim wordDoc As Object
Dim owner, address1, address2, city, state, zipcode, insCo, fax1, name, polnum As String


Dim n, j As Integer

Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

'now we begin the loop for the mailing sheet that is being used

n = wsMailing.Range("A:A").Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For j = 2 To n


    'first we choose which word doc gets used

        'opens the word doc that has the template  for sending out

        Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\cd\LEQ_VOC & Illustration Request.docx")

        'collects the  strings needed for the document
        owner = wsMailing.Range("E" & j).Value
        address1 = wsMailing.Range("F" & j).Value
        address2 = wsMailing.Range("G" & j).Value
        city = wsMailing.Range("H" & j).Value
        state = wsMailing.Range("I" & j).Value
        zipcode = wsMailing.Range("J" & j).Value
        insCo = wsMailing.Range("K" & j).Value
        fax1 = wsMailing.Range("L" & j).Value
        name = wsMailing.Range("M" & j).Value
        polnum = wsMailing.Range("N" & j).Value


        'fills in the word doc with the missing fields
        With wordDoc.Content.Find
            .Execute FindText:="<<InsuranceCompanyName>>", ReplaceWith:=insCo, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            .Execute FindText:="<<Fax1>>", ReplaceWith:=fax1, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            .Execute FindText:="<<OwnerName>>", ReplaceWith:=owner, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            .Execute FindText:="<<Address1>>", ReplaceWith:=address1, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            .Execute FindText:="<<Address2>>", ReplaceWith:=address2, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            .Execute FindText:="<<City>>", ReplaceWith:=city, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            .Execute FindText:="<<State>>", ReplaceWith:=state, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            .Execute FindText:="<<ZipCode>>", ReplaceWith:=zipcode, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            .Execute FindText:="<<Name>>", ReplaceWith:=name, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            .Execute FindText:="<<PolicyNumber>>", ReplaceWith:=polnum, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With


        ' this section saves the word doc in the folder as a pdf
        wordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat "C:\Users\cd\" & wsMailing.Range("N" & j).Value & "_" & wsMailing.Range("C" & j).Value & ".pdf", _
                wdExportFormatPDF


    'need to close word now that it has been opened before the next loop

    wordDoc.Close (wdDoNotSaveChanges)

Next
```