# How to edit an embedded PDF in Excel via VBA and AVDoc?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, adobe

I want to edit a pdf file attached as an object to my Excel doc with VBA.

Background: Since I don't want to share both files in a .zip or else and there is no network drive everybody has granted access to, I need a "foolproof" solution.

The pdf file contains a form (mandatory) and will be filled with information from this Excel doc. As mentioned, I already had a solution with the pdf file stored on a network drive.

```vb
Dim file, new_name As String
Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set AvDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")

'Open new PDF file
'Use local path
file = "C:\Users\992\Desktop\example.pdf"
new_name = "New_PDF_12092019"

If AvDoc.Open(Datei, Name) Then
AcroApp.Show
Set PDDoc = AvDoc.GetPDDoc()
Set jso = PDDoc.GetJSObject

'Get cart ID
jso.getField("Feld1").Value = CStr(ActiveSheet.Range("B12").Value)

'Get Project ID
jso.getField("Feld2").Value = CStr(ActiveSheet.Range("B14").Value)
...
```

My question is: **is there any possibility to use an embedded object with** `AcroExch.AVDoc`?

Since parameter `szFullPath` requires the full path of the file to open, I thought about getting the "path" of the object and use it - but I cannot figure out how. Already tried this: https://danny.fyi/embedding-and-accessing-a-file-in-excel-with-vba-and-ole-objects-4d4e7863cfff

Maybe someone can help me with this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the PDF file is a template, then you could just create that template in Word or Excel, transfer all the data to it and `Document.ExportAsFixedFormat` that to PDF after it has been filled in. [Like This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57629148/how-to-use-vba-to-insert-excel-data-into-word-and-export-it-as-pdf/57634040#57634040)

Comment: @AndrasDorko I haven't built that yet, but it seems like I'd need a prepared word or excel file with a template. This leads to the same path-problem

Comment: The point I was trying to make was that I am not sure you can edit a PDF file from VBA...

Comment: The reason why I don't understand why you would go into all that trouble is, because Having one extra sheet in you Excel Workbook as a template doesn't require any extra objects packaged into your file. Also any Excel Worksheet is perfectly exportable into PDF without any trouble at all. A template Worksheet can even be hidden, and filled in then exported while it is hidden all the way along. I understand you want to do it that way, but is this way lacking any performance, feature or anything else you need?? Just trying to help you... think outside of your potential "box"...

Comment: An extra Excel Worksheet as a template doesn't require any special "Path" to access... correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me with this. The reason I want to use a PDF file is that I need those editable fields in the pdf form. It's necessary for quick changes (so the excel formulas don't need to be changed) and a signature.
example: 
https://imgur.com/a/UhUCCG4

Comment: What Library do I need enabled in Tools -> References to be able to create objects like "AcroExch.App" and "AcroExch.AVDoc" ?

Comment: try these: https://imgur.com/a/L4HymZ3