# How to use BuildingBlockEntry().insert method in Word Document with Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, insert

Most of the code is copied from [How to use VBA to insert Excel data into Word, and export it as PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57629148/how-to-use-vba-to-insert-excel-data-into-word-and-export-it-as-pdf).

Is there is any way to insert text from quickparts-buildingblocks in a Word document via Excel VBA?

This freezes Excel:

```
wordDoc.Application.Templates(...).BuildingBlockEntries("test").Insert Where:=Selection.Range, RichText:=True
```

Code:

```vb
Sub Generate()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Dim wsGenerator As Worksheet
Set wsGenerator = wb.Sheets("List")

Dim wordApp As Word.Application
Set wordApp = New Word.Application

Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Dim name1, name2, name3, name4 As String
Dim n, j As Integer

n = wsGenerator.Range("A:A").Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For j = 2 To n

    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Desktop\ExcelTest\Template.docx")
        
    wordApp.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks

    name1 = wsGenerator.Range("A" & j).Value
    name2 = wsGenerator.Range("B" & j).Value
    name3 = wsGenerator.Range("C" & j).Value
    name4 = wsGenerator.Range("D" & j).Value

    If name4 = "" Then
        wordDoc.Application.Templates( _
          Environ("AppData") & "\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1045\16\Building Blocks.dotx" _
          ).BuildingBlockEntries("test").Insert Where:=Selection.Range, RichText:=True
    End If

    With wordDoc.Content.Find
        .Execute FindText:="<<name1>>", ReplaceWith:=name1, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Execute FindText:="<<name2>>", ReplaceWith:=name2, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Execute FindText:="<<name3>>", ReplaceWith:=name3, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Execute FindText:="<<name4>>", ReplaceWith:=name4, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With

    wordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\ExcelTest\" & wsGenerator.Range("A" & j).Value & " " & wsGenerator.Range("C" & j).Value & ".pdf", _
      wdExportFormatPDF

    wordDoc.Close (wdDoNotSaveChanges)

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: My Word is using `Built-In Building Blocks.dotx` in the same folder so try referring to that instead. Note: The Building Block path can probably be shorten to `Environ("AppData") & "\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1045\16\Building Blocks.dotx"`. Also try changing `wordDoc.Application.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks` to `wordApp.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks`

Comment: Using `Built-In Building Blocks.dotx` nothings changes at this moment. 

I change `wordDoc.Application.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks` to `wordApp.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks` and now i get:

"Run-time error '450':

Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"
with highlighted
`wordDoc.Application.Templates(Environ("AppData") & "\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1045\16\Building Blocks.dotx").BuildingBlockEntries("test").Insert Where:=Selection.Range, RichText:=True`

Comment: Can you update the code in your question?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error (I can insert BB from my `Built-in Building Blocks.dotx` fine) so I'm not sure what else to advise you. Perhaps try breaking down that line for debugging purpose and see what triggers the error (set a variable to the `Template`, then `BuildingBlockEntries`)

Comment: Updated. I've tried both Build-In Building Blocks and Building Blocks.dotx but it doesn't work. Also checked manualy that there is "test" building block in Word's quick parts.

Comment: `doesn't work` as in error 450 occured or what?

Comment: I get error 450 whether or not i use `Built-in Building Blocks.dotx` or `Building Blocks.dotx` in Templates path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

Firstly, `wordDoc.Application` is going to fail because `Application` is not a child object of the document. You have already set a variable, `wordApp` to point to the Word Application object and need to use that.

Secondly, you only need to load the building blocks once, not during each iteration of the loop.

Thirdly, in VBA a variable declaration of:
`Dim name1, name2, name3, name4 As String`
will result in only `name4` being a string whilst all the have the default datatype of Variant.

With these issues corrected your code will be:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Dim wsGenerator As Worksheet
Set wsGenerator = wb.Sheets("List")

Dim wordApp As Word.Application
Set wordApp = New Word.Application

Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Dim name1 As String, name2 As String, name3 As String, name4 As String
Dim n, j As Integer

n = wsGenerator.Range("A:A").Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'load building blocks
Dim bblockSource As String
bblockSource = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1045\16\Building Blocks.dotx"
wordApp.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks

For j = 2 To n

    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Desktop\ExcelTest\Template.docx")
    

    name1 = wsGenerator.Range("A" & j).Value
    name2 = wsGenerator.Range("B" & j).Value
    name3 = wsGenerator.Range("C" & j).Value
    name4 = wsGenerator.Range("D" & j).Value

    If name4 = "" Then
        wordApp.Templates(bblockSource).BuildingBlockEntries("test").Insert Where:=wordApp.Selection.Range, RichText:=True
    End If

    With wordDoc.Content.Find
        .Execute FindText:="<<name1>>", ReplaceWith:=name1, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Execute FindText:="<<name2>>", ReplaceWith:=name2, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Execute FindText:="<<name3>>", ReplaceWith:=name3, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Execute FindText:="<<name4>>", ReplaceWith:=name4, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With

    wordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\ExcelTest\" & wsGenerator.Range("A" & j).Value & " " & wsGenerator.Range("C" & j).Value & ".pdf", _
        wdExportFormatPDF

    wordDoc.Close (wdDoNotSaveChanges)

Next
```

You also need to be aware that your code does not shut Word down after you have finished with it which could lead to multiple hidden instances of Word.

Comment: @AntaRReS96 - Having spent a few minutes scratching my head I realized that there was something in your code I had overlooked. `.Insert Where:=Selection.Range, RichText:=True` fails because Excel also has a `Selection` object so it is getting confused. I have updated the code in my answer with it properly qualified as `wordApp.Selection`